# How Windows cmd transforms the command line when running Perl one-liners?

Tags: windows, perl, shell

I know that Windows shell passes the whole line after an executable name to the executable, and it is task of the executable to parse it.
For instance,

```
C:\Users\osiv\Desktop\>perl -e "use File::Spec; print $_.' ' foreach (File::Spec->splitdir(\"C:\\Users\\osiv\\\"));"
```

should pass all characters after 'perl' to perl.exe found in a %PATH% value directory.

Explain me the output

```
C:\Users\osiv\Desktop\>perl -e "use File::Spec; print $_.' ' foreach (File::Spec->splitdir(\"C:\\Users\\osiv\\\"));"
Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.

C:\Users\osiv\Desktop\>perl -e "use File::Spec; print $_.' ' foreach (File::Spec->splitdir(\"C:\\Users\\osiv\\\\"));"
Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.

C:\Users\osiv\Desktop\>perl -e "use File::Spec; print $_.' ' foreach (File::Spec->splitdir(\"C:\\Users\\osiv\\\\\"));"
C: Users osiv
```

I expected that Perl parses the string passed by Windows shell by looking for strings which should have " at the start and the end. I escape them by \", and expected e.g. `\"osiv\\\\\"));"` to be parsed as `osiv\\`. But, `\"osiv\\\"));"` is not parsed as `osiv\`, so how it is actually parsed?

[Explanation of cmd.exe, CreateProcess command line string metacharacters](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who cares? The [exact rules are convoluted and hard to remember](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/). Just avoid the problem by not using double quotes in your Perl one liners. You know you have `'`, `q{}` and `qq{}` available.

> All of cmd’s transformations are triggered by the presence of one of the metacharacters `(`, `)`, `%`, `!`, `^`, `"`, `<`, `>`, `&`, and `|`. `"` is particularly interesting: when cmd is transforming a command line and sees a `"`, it copies a `"` to the new command line, then begins copying characters from the old command line to the new one without seeing whether any of these characters is a metacharacter. This copying continues until cmd either reaches the end of the command line, runs into a variable substitution, or sees another `"`. In the last case, cmd copies a `"` to the new command line and resumes normal processing. This behavior is almost, but not quite like what CommandLineFromArgvW does with the same character; the difference is that cmd does not know about the `\"` sequence and begins interpreting metacharacters earlier than we would expect.

Also:

`C:\> perl -MFile::Spec::Functions=splitdir -MFile::HomeDir -we "print qq{'$_' } for splitdir home"`

`'C:' 'Users' 'sinan'`

`perl -wE "use File::Spec; print \"'$_' \" for File::Spec->splitdir( \"C:\\Users\\osiv\\\\\" )"`

`'C:' 'Users' 'osiv' ''`

which shows that you should omit the trailing directory separator.

> #### A better method of quoting
>
> While the `"` metacharacter cannot fully protect metacharacters in our command lines against unintended shell interpretation, the `^` metacharacter can. When cmd transforms a command line and sees a `^`, it ignores the `^` character itself and copies the next character to the new command line literally, metacharacter or not. That’s why `^` works as the line continuation character: it tells cmd to copy a subsequent newline as itself instead of regarding that newline as a command terminator. If we prefix with `^` every metacharacter in an argument string, cmd will transform that string into the one we mean to use.

Trying to follow that, the best I can come up with is:

`perl -wE ^"use File::Spec; print \^"'$_' \^" for File::Spec-^>splitdir^(\^"C:\\Users\\osiv\\\\\^"^) ^"`

As I said, avoid `"` in one-liners, make use of `'`, `q{}`, and `qq{}`.